# Migration runs but table is not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running the following migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40

      # t.datetime "created_at"
      # t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end

end
```

But after running `rake db:migrate`, even though the log shows this:

```
== 20150705121953 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0013s
== 20150705121953 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0013s) =============================
```

When I go to the `mysql` console and run `SHOW TABLES;` it displays:

```
mysql> USE my_db;
Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
    Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

If I have the migration create the `users` table, why does the database not show a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem silly but do you have MySQL imported into the rails application? I believe it automatically is setup for SQLite3. I had this issue when I began and have since removed it. It should show this information in the database.yml file.

Joe

Comment: Yup, thats the problem. Thanks, I really appreciate! :)

Comment: You are very welcome! Glad I could be of some help (my first answer provided to Stackoverflow =P).